# Can I Ignore Member State of First Entry for Schengen Visa

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas

I am going to Poland and I have my Schengen Visa taken from Poland embassy. But on my application, I wrote that member state of first entry will be Germany. But now I found a cheaper flight directly to Poland. Can I just go to Poland since it's my main destination point anyway or I should stick to what I wrote on my application form and enter Germany first?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Yes we can!**

You told them your destination was Poland, and you applied at the Polish embassy, and your visa is from Poland, and you directly want to go to Poland. No one is going to bother asking about the German route!

This Schengen Zone concept sometimes makes the most basic things look difficult to a visitor. You're good. Enjoy your trip.

**Hypothetical Q/A**

> Q: Why didn't you come via Germany?
>
> Me: A direct flight is much better, easier and saves me some Euros!